# checking for xml tag element attribute value in oracle clob

Tags: oracle11g

I need to identify all records where there is a tag such as `<hint name="REAL_TIME_TAGGING" value="TRUE">`.
The xml is stored as an oracle clob in a table tab_a(xml clob column: col_a) and the snippet is shown here.

```
<category>
<hints>
    <hint name="NO_DEDUP" value="FALSE"></hint>
    <hint name="REAL_TIME_TAGGING" value="TRUE"></hint>
    more <hint> elements
    <hint ...>
</hints>
<elements>
<element>
...
</element>
</elements>
</category>
```

I can do the below:

```
select * from tab_a where EXTRACTVALUE (XMLTYPE (col_a),'/category/hints/hint[2]/@name') = 'REAL_TIME_TAGGING';
```

But, I am sure there must be a better way using existsnode etc which is not working for me. 
Also, the catch here is hint[2] need NOT be the case. On occasions, it can be anywhere other than in the 2nd position and the above query would fail for other cases where it is not in the hint[2] position.

Any help would be very much appreciated.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: How about /category/hints//hint/@name = 'REAL_TIME_TAGGING' ?  That should look at all <hint> elements.  What do you mean, "existnode etc is not working?"  You get an error, or no results back?  Please show what you are trying in that case.

Comment: Thanks. I have been able to figure it out using existsNode. Was getting an ORA error that I was getting frustrated with. But, now I have eliminated it and is working.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the time spent.
I have been able to figure it out.

Just in case, my solution is:

```
select 
count(1) 
from tab_a
where 
existsNode(xmltype(col_c), '//hints/hint[@name="REAL_TIME_TAGGING"]') = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to query using **dbms_lob.instr** function. Example:

```
select * 
from table 
where dbms_lob.instr(clob_column, 'some content') >= 1
```

Hope it helps. More on this here: https://brunozambiazi.wordpress.com/2015/08/26/finding-a-particular-content-in-oracle-clob-column/